# Как изменить url для сброса пароля на laravel

Tags: php, laravel

При использовании базовой нотификации отправляется письмо для сброса со следующей ссылкой:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/change?token=236359ccf050d6616c4e0405c29df7e9eeee11228e61899836afa5a2db347b876c92&email=admin%40gmail.com
```

При использовании же кастомной нотификации, которую я создаю в папке app\Notifications, url преобразуется уже в динамический вид:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/change/f9f100222f214f2a65fbb1ba46b516bfcc5ee2egca56111917d922cdc5758312.
```

Вот как сделать так, чтобы при использовании моей нотификации, url был таким же,как и при использовании базовой нотификации.

Код ResetPassword (сама нотификация):

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;


class ResetPassword extends Notification
{
    public $token;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Сброс пароля')
            ->line('Вы получили это электронное письмо, потому что мы получили запрос на сброс пароля для вашей учетной записи.')
            ->action('Сбросить пароль', url('password/change', $this->token))
            ->line('Если вы не запрашивали сброс пароля, то, пожалуйста, проигнорируйте данное сообщение.')
            ->salutation('С уважением, Laravel');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно исправить построение `URL` в методе `action` при вызове создании объекта класса `MailMessage`.
Код будет выглядеть примерно следующим:

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Сброс пароля')
        ->line('Вы получили это электронное письмо, потому что мы получили запрос на сброс пароля для вашей учетной записи.')
        ->action('Сбросить пароль', url('/password/change?token={$this->token}')
        ->line('Если вы не запрашивали сброс пароля, то, пожалуйста, проигнорируйте данное сообщение.')
        ->salutation('С уважением, Laravel');
}
```

[Документация по url](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/urls#default-values)